# Navigation from Login screen to Drawer.Navigator first screen Not able to navigate from one screen to drawer navigation

Tags: android, react-native

I am very new to react native and this is my 1st application my org has given me to do a PoC for the same.

My requirement is i have to develop an app with
Login screen -----> Navigation Drawer(1) screen Name--  workProcessor and 2) Operation Analytics)

I am able to achieve screen at 2 different level's

i.e i am able to design Login screen and i am able to design workprocessor and operation analytics screen and switch between them

I am not able to Integrate my login screen and on click of login i should navigate to Navigation-drawer screen

My files are :

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View,
    Button,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import Logo from './Logo';
import Form from './Form';

export default class Login extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Logo></Logo>
                <Form type = "Login"></Form>
                <View style ={styles.workSpaceText}>
                    <Text style = {styles.workSpaceText}> Change WorkSpace ?</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#455a64',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

    workSpaceText: {
        flexGrow:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        
    },

    workSpaceText: {
        fontSize: 15,
        marginVertical:15,
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'
    }
});
```

Form.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const Form = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    loginMove= ()=>{
        
        navigation.navigate('Landing');
    
    } 
      
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                placeholder="Username"
                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff'
            />
            <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff'
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={loginMove}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );


}

export default Form;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    inputBox: {
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
        borderRadius: 25,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#ffffff',
        marginVertical: 10
    },
    button: {
        width: 300,
        backgroundColor: '#1c313a',
        borderRadius: 25,
        marginVertical: 20,
        paddingVertical: 12
    },

    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#ffffff',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});
```

And my Drawer File
i.e LandingScreen.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';

// import { Router, Stack, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import WorkProcessor from './workprocessor';
import OperationAnalytics from './OperationAnalytics';
import { Button, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const NavigationDrawerStructure = (props) => {
  //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleDrawer()}>
        {/*Donute Button Image */}
        <Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/drawerWhite.png' }}
          style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


function firstScreenStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="FirstPage">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="FirstPage"
        component={WorkProcessor}
        options={{
          title: 'Work-Processor', //Set Header Title
          headerLeft: () => <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function secondScreenStack({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SecondPage"
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
        }
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SecondPage"
        component={OperationAnalytics}
        options={{
          title: 'Operational Analytics', //Set Header Title

        }} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
const LandingScreen = () => (

  <NavigationContainer>
   <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
          itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
        }}>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="FirstPage"
          options={{ drawerLabel: 'Work-Processor' }}
          component={firstScreenStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="SecondPage"
          options={{ drawerLabel: 'Operation-Analytics' }}
          component={secondScreenStack} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>

);


export default LandingScreen;
```

When i am clicking on login button i.e loginMove .. it is not moving to navigation drawer screen and giving error: -

***Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.***

Please can some one help me completing this flow. I am ready for doing any code changes it's my PoC

Answer (score 4):

You cannot embedd NavigationContainer, only stacks, drawers, tabs, etc

I suggest you to make two Navigations, one for login, one logged. This prevent to back to login screen when already logged in.

**Example**

```
// App.js
return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        {isLogged ? <LoggedNav /> : <LoginNav />}
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

With your Drawer in LoggedNav and Stacks in LoginNav

**OR**

In a first stack, you have a screen with your drawer stack and one with your landing page stack. You can embedd stacks as much as you want but not NavigationContainer. A screen can be a stack without problems.

```
function Login({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="FirstPage">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="FirstPage"
          component={WorkProcessor}
          options={{
            title: 'Work-Processor', //Set Header Title
            headerLeft: () => <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#f4511e', //Set Header color
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff', //Set Header text color
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold', //Set Header text style
            },
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

const LandingScreen = () => (
     <Drawer.Navigator
          drawerContentOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
            itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
          }}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="FirstPage"
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Work-Processor' }}
            component={firstScreenStack} />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="SecondPage"
            options={{ drawerLabel: 'Operation-Analytics' }}
            component={secondScreenStack} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
);

return(
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="login">
            <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} ... />
            <Stack.Screen name="landing" component={LandingScreen} ... />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Comment: I Dont have to authenticate and all i just have to do is i want to navigate from login to drawer container screen i.e landing screen in which i have my navigation drawer.

and how to create two navigations can you suggest some snippet that would be a great help

Comment: I don't understand, you have a login screen without authentication ? What's the point ?

Comment: It is a PoC brother.. i Don't actually have to authenticate designing the flow is necessary 1st connecting from our product env is 2nd step ..

FLow is Login screen -->  NavigationDrawer screen in that two screens workprocessor and O.A

Comment: any example of code snippet how can i create a stack.for login and drawer. I believe for drawer it is already dere

Comment: Check again answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220029/discussion-between-mayank-purohit-and-bloodymonkey).

Comment: getting error Error: Couldn't register the navigator. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?